# Self-signed certificate for IIS

Tags: ssl-certificate

I want to self-sign a certificate for Internet Information Services(IIS). I want more than just a Common Name. I want the Country, Organization, Organizational Unit, State or Province, Locality, and Email Address as well.
I don't want to send a certification request to a certification authority, because that usually costs money. I want to self-sign a certificate. I think I would like that to be put into a PFX file, so it can be imported into IIS. Any alternative ways to get the self-signed certificate I want?
Either way, where can I find a free certificate generator, to generate a PFX file (with private key)?
Maybe I should post this on serverfault instead...

Comment: So use OpenSSL to do all of that.  You understand by using a self-signed certificate any visitors your website will get a warning right.  And FREE SSL certificates trusted by all browsers exist ( Lets Encrypt)

Comment: @Ramhound I'd have made this an answer.

Comment: No; you just upvoted a comment.